# Orientating subviews differently than parent views

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm basically presenting a series of "documents" (view controllers) in the root view controller. The app itself supports all orientations (the menus and so forth all rotate to accommodate), but once you go into the documents themselves they only support 1 orientation (perhaps landscape, perhaps portrait). So essentially, I want to present something like this:

1. Initial (menus) view happily takes on orientation you choose.
2. Once you click "start" you begin the progression of documents.
3. Each document that is show is shown in its preferred orientation regardless of how the user is holding it. Think of it kind of like a slideshow if you will.

I'm not sure the best way to do this. Whether I should be adjusting the orientation of the whole app, or the individual view controllers. I don't want things to animated rotate, I just want the next one that slides in to be in its own preferred orientation (internally believing the coordinate system is correct, etc.). I know I can just set a transform on the view myself, but that doesn't seem to be the right way to go.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be, that you define a property for each doucment (think of them as objects), let's say `preferredOrientation` property. When that document is chosen, and is going to be loaded, the parent view, which is responsible to both respond to orientation changes and loading (pushing or presenting the document), will respond to orientation change based on the chosen-document-preferred-orientation-property. Does that make sense?

Comment: I actually ended up doing something very similar to this (in other words, you have to do complete manual handling of orientation), so have a vote and answer.